# NodeJS Http status code 413: Increasing body parser limit

Tags: node.js, http, body-parser, http-status-code-413

I am sending an image file from an android client along with some other data. The image is sent as a Base64 string. I am trying to store the image in the server but it returns a 413 http status code.

Some solutions suggested increasing the body-parser limit using, `app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));`, but the code is not in the launcher file `app.js`. How can I do that in another file?

Comment: The `app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));` is a middleware, it means that no matter what, the function will be called before you enter your route. So there is no point to move it away from the app.js

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me: `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '20mb'}));`

Answer (score 0):

I was using express framework & in my case below approach fixed 413 error:-

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.json({limit:'50mb'})); // for incoming Request Object as json

app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:'50mb', extended: true })); // for content-type = application/ x-www-form-urlencoded
```